# How to define your own database ID - Firebase Xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase, xaml, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database:
[image]

And I want to use the "Nome" value as an ID instead of a generated code. Instead of *-MzKveR8JIXgWsrph_or* I wanted it to be *Teste1*.

My current insert code looks like this:

```
 MyDatabaseRecord databaserecord = new MyDatabaseRecord
            {
                Nome = EntryNome.Text.ToString(),
                Prato1 = EntryPrt1.Text.ToString(),
                Prato2 = EntryPrt2.Text.ToString(),
                Sopa = EntrySopa.Text.ToString(),
                Contacto = EntryContacto.Text.ToString()
            };

            firebaseClient.Child("Restaurantes").PostAsync(databaserecord);
```

What do I need to change in order to set the decided value as a Firebase ID? I've been trying to get there but couldn't yet find the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database API for C# follow a REST-ful pattern for its method names. This means that calling `POST` on a URL creates a resource under that location with an identifier determined by the system. If you want to determine your own identifier, call `PUT` on the entire path (including that identifier).

So:

```
firebaseClient.Child("Restaurantes/RestaurantOne").PutAsync(databaserecord);
```